# Get calculations from a JAVA hashset

Tags: java

I have java hashset like this

**Java Hashset**

```
7327896542976267 B ON 17 1381960719243
4116229919133022 B ON 7 1381960779618
2467710535609327 T OFF 5 1381960865253
7327896542976267 B OFF 16 1381961008020
7690519232957130 T ON 1 1381961124863
7690519232957130 T OFF 1 1381961364863
4144171091392103 F ON 1 1381961433257
2332355946816642 B ON 2 1381961601782
4270931484327447 B ON 10 1381961881239
6048000070479064 B ON 3 1381961959977
4270931484327447 B OFF 10 1381962121239
6056389598100654 T ON 13 1381962380866
5270503505599671 B ON 8 1381962381419
6048000070479064 B OFF 2 1381962588710
6056389598100654 T OFF 13 1381962620866
3873532220632004 T ON 1 1381962807491
3873532220632004 T OFF 1 1381963047491
3495435380122245 B ON 10 1381963314807
3495435380122245 B OFF 10 1381963554807 ................
```

**Explanation -**

This is information about passenger travelling of a public transport system,

3495435380122245(card number) B(transport type) ON(start travelling) 10 (travelling zone) 1381963314807 (time)

3495435380122245(card number) B(transport type) OFF(finish travelling) 15 (travelling zone) 1381963314807 (time)

**QUESTION**

This hashset has multiple entries for each passenger card number,

As a example, in above explanation that person travel 5 zones. How can I calculate this for each passenger? And how can I make a new hashset with new calculated values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with objects will make your life much easier. For example a `Trip` object can hold information like card number, transport type, start time, finish time, start zone, finish zone, zone difference etc.

It will take one pass to your hashset to create another collection of such `Trip` objects. This collection can be a map (with card number as keys and `Trip` as values) if you want to search trips using card numbers later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the entries by time and replay them to build a state for each customer. With each event you add any charges incurred and at the end you know how much each customer's fee were.

BTW You can't sort a HashSet but you can sort an array or ArrayList.